# Узнать часовой пояс php

Tags: php, время

Имеется город в русской раскладке к примеру (Москва), а точнее имеется база практически из всех городов мира, как определить временную зону в каждом из городов? Есть ли API возвращающие данные по городу?

P.S PHP

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%B0+%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: узнать не вручную!!! Вы читали?

Comment: я то читал. А вы не знаете что такое парсинг? Берёте подходящий сайт и парсите с него данные или связываетесь с админами и если они вменяемые, то вполне могут поделиться базой город-часовой пояс.

Comment: парсинг тут не подойдет(я имею ввиду по страницам)

Comment: Вы меня не поняли видимо. Вы парсите все города составляя свою таблицу соответствий, потом импортируете ее в свою базу на сайте и пользуетесь данными из своей базы. В реальном времени парсить не нужно.

Comment: по одному лишь названию населённого пункта — задача нерешаема. ведь даже для приведённого примера (москва) есть [несколько населённых пунктов, находящихся в разных часовых поясах](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0_%28%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29#.D0.9D.D0.B0.D1.81.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.91.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.BF.D1.83.D0.BD.D0.BA.D1.82.D1.8B).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть GeoIP API в PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.geoip.php
Вам нужна функция geoip_time_zone_by_country_and_region()

Comment: читал я про гео, но там нужно знать коды стран и код региона, если код страны там еще можно получить что мне делать с кодом региона(

Comment: Там есть функция geoip_region_by_name, которая возвращает код региона по его названию.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.geoip-country-code-by-name.php мне в параметр адрес хоста задать нужно, а мне нужно по городу!

Comment: Тогда есть Google Time Zone API. Там сначала конечно надо зарегестрироваться, но должно работать не плохо. Там есть ограничения конечно... 2500 запросов в сутки и 5 запросов в секунду.
Вот ссылка: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro

Comment: уже курю в его сторону, правда с костылями в плане от туда получит название к примеру Europe/Moscow, ему передав координаты с карты (определив их), за тем в самом php укажем таймзону и получим время, но это такие себе кастыли..... А так же не получается ключ получить,PS имеется даже консоль разработчика

Comment: Если надо быстро, то найдите таблицу всех городов и time zones и загрузите себе в базу.

Comment: Такую таблицу не найти(в открытом) Да сделаю проще, я знаком с яндекс картами(написал скрипт который по названию возвращает координаты) потом в гугл API смотрю регион(не беру смещение от туда так как у москвы до сих порт смещение +4, а уже как год +3) изменю таймзону и воаля получаю нужное мне время - бинго(оброс кастылями)