# как актуализировать время для разных зон с учетом летнего времени?

Tags: php, время

На корпоративном портале, где пользователи были только из России, временные зоны устанавливались простым смещением относительно UTC, о летнем/зимнем времени речи не шло. Время событий в базе - в формате unixtime, а часовой пояс для пользователя - целое число, и все хорошо работало, в пределах РФ.
 Но теперь там будут работать партнеры из Америки (вся северная, часть Латинской), Европы (вся), и совсем немного из Океании и Азии. Поверхностное гугление меня немного расстроило: перевод на летнее время в разных регионах поисходит в разные дни, да и в пределах страны (США, Австралия) в разных штатах по-разному, и что с этим делать я совершенно не представляю.

Comment: Попробуйте узнавать время пользователя через JavaScript и передавать его на сервер через куки. Пример JS [библиотеки](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js). А вообще через PHP делать это не комильфо. Слишком много нюансов, которые не дадут точного результата в автоопределении.

Comment: Rootware, вот за нюансами я и пришел. Всё должно выполнятся на стороне сервера, допустим, клиент в настройках выбирает часовой пояс, ставит галку "переводить на летнее время" - и тут начинается непонятное: когда переводить? На сколько переводить? Может, в какой-нибудь стране даже не на час переводится, а на 15 минут?

Comment: В конце концов, решил так: JS-ом узнаю локальное время, получаю смещение от UTC, и вывожу пользователю времена событий с учетом этого смещения, а если локаьное время не правильное - проблемы пользователя, хоть что-то должно же быть на их совести? Отмечу ответ mymedia за интересные ссылки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перескажу вкратце статью ["Never say never" или Работаем с таймзонами правильно](https://habrahabr.ru/post/242645) в блоге @Mail.Ru.

1. Храните метки времени в двух представлениях: локальном для пользователя и глобальном в UTC.
2. Перед выводом даты и времени спросите местоположение пользователя или попытайтесь его угадать.

   - [GeoIP API в PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453729)
   - [Преобразования времени на клиенте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/635215)
3. Конвертируйте время события из UTC в требуемое локальное.